# Force android studio to use class defined in my android package

Tags: android

How one can force android studio to use class defined in my android package instead one provided by Google? 
I created a fresh new android project with android studio 3.3 and added one class

```
package android.support.v7.app;

import android.app.Activity;

public class AppCompatActivity extends Activity{

}
```

Then if I use AppCompatActivity and try to build it shows error :

> Error: Program type already present: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity

There is answer present for the error `Program type already present` but is not applicable in this case.

Comment: You would need to identify the specific library that contains `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity`, then block it from being included in your dependencies.

Comment: I created a fresh new android project, and added no extra dependencies myself.

Comment: The new project wizard automatically sets up some dependencies, based on the template that you chose.

Comment: I want to override android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity, but with same name and package, so can I say android studio to use this one particular class from file I placed in android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.java and all other support-v7 classes use as it is?

Comment: "I want to override android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity, but with same name and package" -- that is not possible, if by "override" you mean "extend via a subclass". You can create a subclass of `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity` under a different name or package. Or, you can have your own `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity` that extends from something else.

Comment: "can I say android studio to use this one particular class from file I placed in android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.java and all other support-v7 classes use as it is?" -- you would have to identify the library that contains `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity`, make a copy, remove `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity` from that copy, then use that copy in your dependencies.

Comment: By override I want to override use of that particular classfile. When android studio sets up new project it will use ``android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity`` class from SDK installed on system. Right? But I don't want to let it use from sdk. If posiible only that file, else any other solution.

Comment: "When android studio sets up new project it will use android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity class from SDK installed on system" -- I do not know what "installed on system" means. All classes in `android.support.v7` packages come from libraries that you request in your module's `build.gradle` file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198828/discussion-between-laraflow-and-commonsware).

Answer (score 0):

Change the package name for you project from `package android.support.v7.app` to anything else and each time you would want to use `AppCompatActivity` Android studio will let you choose the desired class.

The problem is that Android studio knows about AppCompat by default and it will not let you use this namespace that easy.

Comment: Yes Android studio knows AppCompat. I want make android studio ignore that 'knowledge' for particular one file, else for AppCompat itself.

Comment: You can build the project directly via gradle from terminal without android studio. Or write a plugin for android studio to ignore appcompat.

Comment: Do you have idea on 'write a plugin for android studio to ignore appcompat' or some online guide, contents on writing plugin is available on internet, but for this specific purpose ,how should I quick start?

Comment: Nope - sorry. You may start from https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started.html though. You can also try to force an Android studio to use AndroidX instead of appcompat - I didn't try but it may help. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate